# Long wait for the first request in the time of authorization or registration of Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use in my application Firebase Database and at the time of the first request for authorization or registration, I wait for a long time for the data.

The first request takes about 5-6 minutes and sometimes more. I suspect that my app caches all the information from the database and did the cancellation of this action by setting a flag in `keepSynced NO`.

But even this did not help and I had to wait a very long time. All subsequent requests are quickly and data come instantly. Below is the code that I use on the first request.

```
self.ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
[self.ref keepSynced:NO];

[self.ref observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    self.fireUser = [TSFireUser initWithSnapshot:snapshot];
    [self configureController];

}];
```

code model:

```
TSFireUser *user = [[TSFireUser alloc] init];

NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"token"];
FIRUser *fireUser = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;
if(token)
{

    NSString *keyUserData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataBase/users/%@/userData", fireUser.uid];
    NSString *keyToParameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataBase/users/%@", fireUser.uid];
    NSString *keyToPhotos = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dataBase/users/%@", fireUser.uid];

    FIRDataSnapshot *fireUser = [snapshot childSnapshotForPath:keyUserData];
    FIRDataSnapshot *fireUserParameters = [snapshot childSnapshotForPath:keyToParameters];
    FIRDataSnapshot *fireUserPhotos = [snapshot childSnapshotForPath:keyToPhotos];

    FIRDataSnapshot *userIdent = fireUser.value[@"userID"];
    FIRDataSnapshot *userName = fireUser.value[@"displayName"];
    FIRDataSnapshot *userEmail = fireUser.value[@"email"];
    FIRDataSnapshot *userPhoto = fireUser.value[@"photoURL"];
    FIRDataSnapshot *dateOfBirth = fireUser.value[@"dateOfBirth"];
    FIRDataSnapshot *age = fireUser.value[@"age"];
    FIRDataSnapshot *location = fireUser.value[@"location"];
    FIRDataSnapshot *gender = fireUser.value[@"gender"];
    FIRDataSnapshot *online = fireUser.value[@"online"];
    FIRDataSnapshot *parameters = fireUserParameters.value[@"parameters"];
    FIRDataSnapshot *photos = fireUserPhotos.value[@"photos"];


    user.uid = (NSString *)userIdent;
    user.displayName = (NSString *)userName;
    user.email = (NSString *)userEmail;
    user.photoURL = (NSString *)userPhoto;
    user.dateOfBirth = (NSString *)dateOfBirth;
    user.age = (NSString *)age;
    user.location = (NSString *)location;
    user.gender = (NSString *)gender;
    user.online = (NSString *)online;
    user.parameters = (NSMutableDictionary *)parameters;
    user.photos = (NSMutableArray *)photos;

}
```

I would be grateful for any provided assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Is the first code you posted, the call to observeEventType, the code that is taking a long time to complete? And what does the configureController method do? Does it do any UIKit code, like setting up a view controller or view objects?

Does FireBase call it's completion handlers on a background thread? (You can either check the docs or test it by reading the value of `Thread.isMainThread` inside your completion handler.

Comment: Method [self configureController]; configures the controller, sets the user avatar and adds all the parameters labels. Name, age, sex and place of residence user. You offer to run the code in a background thread, asynchronously. But then the controller would be empty a 5 minute ... If I understood you correctly...